# Why is this head method without a return type or void declaration?

Tags: java

I have a question.
I have these attributes:

```
private int x;
private int y;
```

Why here don't we write the return type:

```
public dispenser (){
   x=9;
   y=0;
}
```

and here with "void":

```
public void two (){
   x=y-1;
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: The first one is a constructor (assuming your class name is `dispenser`). The second one is a method. _" Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have **no** return type."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public dispenser (){
  x=9;
  y=0;
}
```

This is a constructor and Constructors have same name as that of a class and have no return type. It will be called as soon as you create an object of your class.

```
public void two (){
   x=y-1;
}
```

The second one is a method. This will be called when you want or call it. Methods have a return type. In your case you have made it `void`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the first one is a constructor and the second one is a method,

constructors are called when you created the object of your class and will assign value to parameters ,

methods are called when you want

Answer (score 0):

start with basics of java.

1. whats return type do.
2. Acces Specifiers

every java method has return type.

only the constructor doesnt have return type

Answer (score 0):

```
public dispenser(){
    x=9;
    y=0;

}
```

This is a constructor it is used to instantiate an object. It does not return a value at all which is why it does not require a return type.

```
public void two(){
   x=y-1;
}
```

This is a method that returns nothing hence the word void. For a method a return type needs to be provided and the keyword void makes it so the method does not actually return a value.

```
public int three(){
    return 3;
}
```

This method returns an integer value. And the keyword int in the prototype ensures this.